# Redirect like via `/etc/hosts` without editing `/etc/hosts`

Tags: linux, redirect, localhost

I need to redirect particular outgoing connections (from ***any*** web-client on my system) to particular IP. Yes, it can be done by adding this line in `/etc/hosts` file:

```
123.456.789.012  www.mydomain.com
```

Is it possible to do such a redirection *without* editing of `/etc/hosts`? In fact, I need this redirection temporarily. Moreover, I cannot modify any configuration files on my system, so I should do such a redirection only via some utils in the command line. I've read about `tsocks`, but it can redirect outgoing connections to SOCKS server only from the particular application, not from *any* application.

So, is it possible?

Comment: Add an iptables rule?

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I found a solution. We can use `iptables` for it. This rule redirects all outgoing requests via `80` port to `0.0.0.0:3010`:

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 0.0.0.0:3010
```

To delete this rule, just replace `-A` to `-D`:

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -D OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 0.0.0.0:3010
```

If we want to redirect only particular requests via `80` port, we can use this command:

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d google.com --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 0.0.0.0:3010
```

In this case only requests to `google.com` will be redirected to `0.0.0.0:3010`.